# Global Dashboard

Tags: drupal-views, dashboard, dashlet

I just created a new dashlet via Views to show a list of case managers. Is there a way I can add this dashlet to all my current users' dashboards? I know there is the Default Dashlet extension, but that only seems to apply to new users.

Are there other workarounds that I could possibly reset all my users dashboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround:

You could add a (Drupal) block, and choose it only to display on a certain page; CiviCRM home. (And maybe also by selecting only to show with specific roles)

Comment: Wow, that's a very creative workaround! If there's a way to control having blocks appear side by side, that would be awesome. Any suggestions? Since the main CiviCRM homepage isn't a node, both Panels and Display Suite wouldn't work here.

Comment: Edited: I take it back! Layouts can be edited with mini-panels. This is awesome! Thanks Flying!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could be of help:-)

Comment: Just remember that CiviCRM Home page will be accessed both from civicrm and civicrm/dashboard